# Why isn't it possible to use the component of the weight in the direction of $$ to find $$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, vectors, weight, free-body-diagram

Say, in the example below, the weight $mg$ of the object is $800N$. To find $R$, the conventional method is to use $R\sin(28^\circ) = 800$.

But why isn't it possible to use instead the component of the weight in the direction of $R$ to find $R$? That component would be $ 800\cos(62^\circ)$, but equating it to $R$ arrives at a small, incorrect answer for $R$.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider your diagram in context. I would guess that the diagram is of a conical pendulum. In that case we know the mass isn't moving up or down, so we know that the net vertical force must be zero. The downwards force is $mg$ and the upwards force is $R\sin\theta$, so we simply set them equal.

Comment: I got it after some thinking and reading your comment. Thanks